# np.save doesn't save the whole array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm receiving a stream from `rtsp` protocol divided into `numpy.ndarray` frames, and I'm just trying to save the frame into `image.npy` so that other modules can load this image.

I've used `np.save` and `np.load` as shown in this snippet:

- Sender:

```py
while True:
    frame = rtsp_module.get_next_frame()
    print(type(frame), frame.shape)
    # <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1080, 1920, 3)
    np.save("image.npy", frame)
```

- Receiver:

```py
while True:
    frame = np.load("image.npy")
    print(type(frame), frame.shape)
```

For the first couple of frames it works fine, but then at one random frame I get this error:

`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6,217,425 into shape (1080,1920,3).`

So I assumed that the numpy.save doesn't save the whole array for some reason.

- Things I tried and didn't work:

  1. I tried to add some delay after I save and I load the numpy array
  2. Checked that the server sends the right array every time

Comment: Hard to reproduce but could it be that you try loading - right a the moment -when you are writing the array? Are those two while loops are running in two separate processes?

Comment: Full traceback please.  Is this error in the `load` itself, or some following operation?

Comment: @some_name.py, Yes they're running on two different processes

Comment: @hpaulj, yes this error is in the `np.load` itself

Comment: @MohamedMostafa I think this error occurs when the speed of writing and reading is difference. So when you add some delay after saving and loading the numpy array doesn't work after certain time. Solution is: add flag "done" when finish save process. And load process 
only execute when the flag is "done".

Comment: @ViettelSolutions Actually that worked, it's slower but it's working. I guess I need different type of inter process communication between modules. anyway thank you for figuring it out, can you please add this as an answer.

Comment: @MohamedMostafa okie. i added this as an answer. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error occurs when the speed of writing and reading is difference. So when you add some delay after saving and loading the numpy array doesn't work after certain time. Solution is: add flag "done" when finish save process. And load process only execute when the flag is "done".